# Custom config of a lua plugin in Neovim

Tags: plugins, lua, neovim

I do not know how to write configs in lua. I am using neovim and my configartion is written in lua. I have few plugins and I use lazy nvim as my plugin manager.

I have a seperate plugins directory which holds my plugins' lua files. I currently have the below as my indent-blankline.lua file:

```
local Plugin = {'lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim'}

Plugin.name = 'indent_blankline'

Plugin.main = 'ibl'

Plugin.event = {'BufReadPost', 'BufNewFile'}

-- See :help ibl.setup()
Plugin.opts = {
  enabled = false,
  scope = {
    enabled = false,
  },
  indent = {
    char = '▏',
  },
}

return Plugin
```

I want to add the config below which I found in the github page of the plugin. It will apply colors to the lines:

```
local highlight = {
    "RainbowRed",
    "RainbowYellow",
    "RainbowBlue",
    "RainbowOrange",
    "RainbowGreen",
    "RainbowViolet",
    "RainbowCyan",
}

local hooks = require "ibl.hooks"
-- create the highlight groups in the highlight setup hook, so they are reset
-- every time the colorscheme changes
hooks.register(hooks.type.HIGHLIGHT_SETUP, function()
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowRed", { fg = "#E06C75" })
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowYellow", { fg = "#E5C07B" })
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowBlue", { fg = "#61AFEF" })
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowOrange", { fg = "#D19A66" })
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowGreen", { fg = "#98C379" })
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowViolet", { fg = "#C678DD" })
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowCyan", { fg = "#56B6C2" })
end)

require("ibl").setup { indent = { highlight = highlight } }
```

I am not sure how/where to place the above. I wonder if someone can tell me how do I integrate this to my config.

Comment: You may be able to find better answers at https://vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lazy.nvim plugins, you want to return a table containing a config function. Inside the config function, you can pass your options to Indent Blankline's `setup()` function, as well as register your hooks. This code returns the table directly, but you could also build it up and then return it, as you've done above.

```lua
-- nvim/lua/plugins/indent-blankline.lua

return {
    {
        "lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim",
        name = "indent_blankline",
        event = { "BufReadPost", "BufNewfile" },
        config = function()
            local highlight = {
                "RainbowRed",
                "RainbowYellow",
                "RainbowBlue",
                "RainbowOrange",
                "RainbowGreen",
                "RainbowViolet",
                "RainbowCyan",
            }

            require("ibl").setup({
                indent = { char = "│", highlight = highlight, },
                scope = { enabled = false },
            })

            local hooks = require("ibl.hooks")

            hooks.register(hooks.type.HIGHLIGHT_SETUP, function()
                vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowRed", { fg = "#E06C75" })
                vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowYellow", { fg = "#E5C07B" })
                vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowBlue", { fg = "#61AFEF" })
                vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowOrange", { fg = "#D19A66" })
                vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowGreen", { fg = "#98C379" })
                vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowViolet", { fg = "#C678DD" })
                vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowCyan", { fg = "#56B6C2" })
            end)
        end,
    },
}


-- nvim/init.lua (if your color scheme does not already provide these highlight groups)

vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowRed", { fg = "#E06C75", })
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowYellow", { fg = "#E5C07B", })
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowBlue", { fg = "#61AFEF", })
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowOrange", { fg = "#D19A66", })
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowGreen", { fg = "#98C379", })
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowViolet", { fg = "#C678DD", })
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "RainbowCyan", { fg = "#56B6C2", })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried the first config above, re-installed the indent-blankline plugin, ran update and sync for lazy manager; I got the below error message: `Failed to run config for indent-blankline .../share/nvim/lazy/indent-blankline/lua/ibl/highlights.lua:70: No highlight group Rainbow found #stacktrace .... .... `

Comment: If your color scheme doesn't provide those highlight groups, then you'll need to define them yourself, using `vim.api.nvim_set_hl()` in`init.lua`. The code is identical to what you're running inside `hooks.register()` Color schemes may not have included these values yet, because Indent Blankline v3 is quite new. I'll edit the answer to be more explicit.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thank you.